# Understanding equality sign in context of big-O-notation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

I am not quite sure if I have understood correctly the equality sign when using big-O-notation. Let's consider the following example of a sequence:

$\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}:= 5+f(n)$, where $f(n)$ is some function of $n$.

Now, we assume that we can prove that $f(n)$ has the same asymptotic behavior like $\frac{1}{n}$ and hence $f(n)=O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ (or some would say $f(n)\in O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$). In many proofs this makes the authors write:
$$
 \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}5+f(n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}5+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=5.
$$
However, our tutor said that if we write this and then argue that the limit is $5$ he will deduct points. (note that I am 2nd year undergraduate student) So I wonder if the following reasoning is what justifies this "equality":

As $f(n)\in O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ we know that there exists a constant $C$ and an index $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$: $$|f(n)|\leq C\Big|\frac{1}{n}\Big|\implies 5-C\frac{1}{n}\leq f(n)\leq 5+C\frac{1}{n}~\underset{\text{lemma}}{\underset{\text{squeeze}}{\implies}}~ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}5+f(n)=5.$$

So whenever we make use of big-O-notation we should bear in mind that the $O(\cdot)$ sign represents a function which has certain properties. Exploiting those properties allows us to derive the limit (e.g. $f\in O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$) or sometimes these properties doesn't help us at all when deriving a limit (e.g. $f\in O(1)$).

Is this correct? Or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: For me, it is quite correct, and I really don't understand why your tutor said such a thing. This is basic in asymptotic analysis.

Comment: You are right. I dk why the tutor has an objection.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, the question is: how would you argue withput my additional explanation? Which rules would you use? Would you simply say that $O(\frac{1}{n})$ is a function which has the same asymptotic behavior like $\frac{1}{n}$? Then what does this mean?

Comment: @Bernard what is the exact argument for proving $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}5+f(n)=5$ when you argue with *asymptotic analysis*? I mean you must derive $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}5+f(n)=5$ from the fact that $f(n)\in O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\Big|\frac{f(n)}{\frac{1}{n}}\Big|<\infty$? I don't know how to do this.

Comment: It's elementary: $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl(5+f(n),\bigr)=5+ \lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=5$ since you 've shown (which wasn't really necessary, in my opinion) that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$.

Comment: @Bernard, I don't understand what you have in mind when you talk about *asymptotic analysis*. If you say that it's not necessary to show $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$ then how would you show $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}5+f(n)=0$ instead? Either you have implicitly used the rules of limits (like I did) or you've used something different which might refer to the notion of *asymptotic analysis*. If the latter is true then I would be happy if you elaborate.

Comment: I had in mind nothing special. Asymptotic analysis is about all these concepts about the behavious of function at infinity or in the neighbourhood of a point (equivalence of functions,, $O(f)$ or $ o(f)$. It is obvious that a function of $n$ which is $O(\frac1n)$ tends to $0$ at at infinity.

Comment: @Bernard, sorry I got a little bit confused. I only wanted to be sure that the underlying reason for the claim: **"if $f(n)\in O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ it follows $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$"** is that we can squeeze $f(n)$ between $-\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ as I did in my original approach. Or more generally, everytime we make claims on limits which are based on the fact that a function $f(n)$ has the property $f(n)\in O(g(n))$ we use this property to apply rules of limits. Sometimes applying those rules is obvious (as in my example) and sometimes it needs more reasoning. Right?

Comment: That quite right. Some of my teachers used  to say, as  a proof, that ‘a moment thinking will convince you that …’.

Comment: @Bernard, unfortunately I have done too many mistakes recently. So at the moment it's hard to trust in my own thinking. Thanks for your help and explanations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't read minds, but the tutor's concern may be that $O(1/n)$ is a set of functions rather than an arbitrary function in that set (unless we achieve the latter with an abuse of notation), so $\lim_{n\to\infty}(5+O(1/n))$ is undefined even though $\lim_{n\to\infty}(5+f)$ has the same value for all $f\in O(1/n)$.

Comment: Some people, especially modern number theorists, treat O(g(n)) as a function to avoid some cumbersome terminology and notation.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I'm guessing this tutor isn't one of them, at least not for education purposes.

Comment: @J.G., I talked again with my tutor and this is exactly what he had in mind. He told us that we shouldn't use the $O$-sign in equations (at least in this stage of maths studies) but rather replace it by a function $f\in O(1/n)$. Then, $f$ being of class $O(1/n)$ has certain properties which might be helpful (like in this case) or not to show convergence.